# WebEngineView: disable content selection

Tags: qt, qml

How to disable selecting content in WebEngineView in QML?

```
WebEngineView {
    id: webEngineView
    width: 600 * contentZoomFactor
    height: parent.height
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    zoomFactor: contentZoomFactor

    onContextMenuRequested: {
        request.accepted = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can simply create a transparent rectangle over webenginview with mouseArea and handle mouse event there

Comment: I want to disable only selecting content, other features like url clicks should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by injecting a bit of JavaScript to set a style on the body that disables selection.

Here's an example:

Create a JavaScript file called disableUserSelection.js with just one function:

```
(function () {
    document.body.style.webkitUserSelect = 'none';
    document.body.style.webkitUserDrag = 'none';
})();
```

Then inject that into your web page as a UserScript:

```
WebEngineScript {
id: disableSelectionScript
injectionPoint: WebEngineScript.DocumentReady
sourceUrl: "qrc:/disableUserSelection.js"
worldId: WebEngineScript.MainWorld
}

userScripts: [disableSelectionScript]
```

That should do the trick.